# PHP mPDF base64 image error - could not find image file ()

Tags: php, image, mpdf

According [documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/images.html#embedded-image-data) I would like to use mpdf with base64 image to preview img tag in document. Everything should be ok, if I show the base64 image in html page it wortks fine. But mpdf throws me an error:

> Could not find image file ()

The code looks like this and as I said in html it works but not in mpdf:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG8AAA....."
```

Can somebody tell me please what is wrong? Documentation is simple. Why mpdf does not recognize base64 data? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that's actually the image element that is causing the error ...?

Comment: If I remove it from the code it works. What else could it be?

Comment: What happens when you set `showImageErrors` to true as the documentation suggests, to debug image errors?

Comment: I wrote it in the question. Mpdf throws an error Could not find image file ()

Comment: Yeah, I was asking whether that gives any additional info.

Comment: Its commont php exception with callstack which does not make sence if it try tor find file according base64 string.